# Varnish Cache - default TTL?

Tags: varnish, cache, ttl

I have discovered that I can set the TTL in Varnish as follows in my VCL file:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
    # 1 minute
    set obj.ttl = 1m;
}
```

But what is the default setting (assuming the backend server is setting no cache-control header) ?

Comment: Looks like I've found the answer: 120 seconds - this is in the default VCL logic.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is in the default template:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
    if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
        beresp.http.Set-Cookie ||
        beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
                /*
                 * Mark as "Hit-For-Pass" for the next 2 minutes
                 */
                set beresp.ttl = 120 s;
                return (hit_for_pass);
    }
    return (deliver);
}
```

So, 120 seconds.

Comment: Where did you find the default template?

Comment: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html

Comment: There is a default.vcl that ships with varnish as of at least 3.0.3 which has all of the default config subroutines commented out in it. The 4.0 default config can be seen here: https://github.com/mattiasgeniar/varnish-4.0-configuration-templates/blob/master/default.vcl

Comment: This doesn't mirror my observations. It is true that the default ttl is 120 seconds, but the source of this number can't be that snippet. If it were, objects without a ttl would be marked as hit_for_pass, but they actually remain in the cache for 120 seconds.

Comment: You'll find the source of the builtin vcl here - https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/master/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl. Use the `varnish-<version>` tags to see the version for your Varnish release.

Answer (score 34):

Default TTL can be passed through the varnishd command via the `-t` commandline switch and is probably sourced from a properties file on your filesystem. On the CentOS system I'm looking at it is set using `DEFAULT_TTL` from `/etc/sysconfig/varnish`.

You can see the live setting using varnishadm like so,

```
varnishadm param.show default_ttl
```

Actually, following default VCL logic relates to non-cacheable objects.

```
  sub vcl_fetch {
      if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
          beresp.http.Set-Cookie ||
          beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
                  /*
                   * Mark as "Hit-For-Pass" for the next 2 minutes
                   */
                  set beresp.ttl = 120 s;
                  return (hit_for_pass);
      }
      return (deliver);
  }
```

means "if object is not cacheable - pass client requests for this object to backend directly and simultaneously for 2 minutes, do not queue them"

Read more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691489/varnish-hit-for-pass-means